# Why jquery return Object in attr('src')

Tags: javascript, jquery

This return me object Object. how can make an array of src?

```
$('#mainContainerPortfolio #activateBox').click(function(){

    var clickedAlt = $(this).children('img').attr('alt');
    var imgs = $('#mainContainerPortfolio #projectImg[alt="'+clickedAlt+'"]');
    imgs.src;
    var i = [];
    i.push(imgs);

    console.log(i);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `imgs` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element.  As such, it does not have a `.src` property.

If you want the `.src` property of an image in that jQuery object, then you need to do one of the following:

```
var src = imgs.attr("src");
```

or, get the first DOM element from the jQuery object:

```
var src = imgs[0].src
```

---

Also, there are several other errors in your code.  If you want to accumulate the `src` value of all elements that are clicked on into an array, you could do something like this:

```
$('#mainContainerPortfolio #activateBox').click(function(){

    var clickedAlt = $(this).children('img').attr('alt');
    var imgs = $('#mainContainerPortfolio #projectImg[alt="'+clickedAlt+'"]');
    var srcs = imgs.map(function(index, elem) {
        return(elem.src);
    }).get();

    console.log(srcs);
});
```

---

I think there is also a problem with your selector because you can only have one element with an `id="projectImg"` so there should be no reason to be using the attribute [alt="'+clickedAlt+'"] with it.

Similarly, `'#mainContainerPortfolio #activateBox'` could just be changed to `'#activateBox'` since there can only be one object with an id of `activateBox`.

Comment: @Sam - please note my additional comments about your selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Because `imgs` *is* an object. This line:

```
imgs.src;
```

does nothing at all. It just returns that. Nothing is done with the returned value. Change that to:

```
imgs = imgs.attr("src");
```

and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

You could use .map to get an array.

```
i = imgs.map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('src');
});
```